# Right way to set memory parameters for LocalCluster in dask

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I tried the code below,

```
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster
worker_kwargs = {
    'memory_limit': '2G',
    'memory_target_fraction': 0.6,
    'memory_spill_fraction': 0.7,
    'memory_pause_fraction': 0.8,
    'memory_terminate_fraction': 0.95,
}
cluster = LocalCluster(ip='0.0.0.0', n_workers=8, **worker_kwargs)
```

but it doesn't work

```
...
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'memory_target_fraction'
```

What's the right way to call? LocalCluster doesn't seem to care about `~/.config/dask/distributed.yaml`, either.

I've read about these posts:

1. https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/2456
2. https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/1521

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it's a version issue. Updating dask to 1.2.0 solves the problem.

```
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster
worker_kwargs = {
    'memory_limit': '2G',
    'memory_target_fraction': 0.6,
    'memory_spill_fraction': 0.7,
    'memory_pause_fraction': 0.8,
    # 'memory_terminate_fraction': 0.95,
}
cluster = LocalCluster(ip='0.0.0.0', n_workers=8, **worker_kwargs)
```

works

Comment: But it still doesn't seem to be working, I asked here, https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/2456#issuecomment-485265025

Comment: It's deprecated now, use     dask.config.set(
        {
            "distributed.worker.memory.target": 0.6,
            "distributed.worker.memory.spill": 0.7,
            "distributed.worker.memory.pause": 038,                                    
            "distributed.worker.memory.terminate": 0.95,

        }
    )